# graphing a trigonometric, polynomial, quadratic functions without calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently a calculus teacher started by a sketch of precalculus, as I was sick I didn't attend the lectures, though he delayed the exam for me for two weeks. One of the themes he covered, was graphing sets on planes,and graphing trigonometric functions, quadratic, and polynomial ones without calculus, and I don't know what can be the best way to approach such problems. 
If you can shed some light please?

Comment: Even without calculus, you can still try finding the $x$ and $y$ intercepts, and also find the roots using the rational root theorem. Then you can plot the points every half a unit or every unit. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @TobyMak, Yes, do you think of any other ways.

Comment: What is stopping you from graphing then?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there are some good ways that will help more in terms of data on how to graph such functions.

Comment: Plot more points I guess? You really need a specific function, and what you have attempted so others have a better idea of what you are asking.

Comment: I am just asking so I can find more ease with getting the right directions to infinity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99384/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-v-head).

Answer (score 1):

< When I answered I assumed that trigonometric functions referred simply to sine, cosine, and tangent. I also discuss polynomials more in detail at the end.>

When you are graphing functions, make sure to SIZE them up
(Symmetry - Intercept - Zeroes - End Behavior)
and consider other components which will be discussed.

For symmetry, you are checking whether a function is "odd" or "even" or not symmetrical.

Odd functions occur when f(-x) = -f(x). That is, each output of x has the same magnitude y as those of -x, but for each -x the result is -y. Graphically this looks like you take the values in the first quadrant and rotate them 180 degrees so that the values in the first and third quadrants overlap.

Meanwhile, even functions occur when f(-x) = f(x). That is, each output of x has the same value of y as each output -x. Graphically this looks like you flip the values across the y-axis so that the values in the first and second quadrants overlap. It is important to note that translating graphs (moving them left/right or up/down) eliminates symmetry.

For the (non-translated) functions you mentioned, quadratics and cosine functions have even symmetry, and the sine and tangent functions have odd symmetry.

For all of the functions you mentioned, the domain of x is all real numbers. This guarantees that you will have a y-intercept. This is simply evaluated by finding y when x = 0. By the definition of a function, you will have only 1 y-intercept.

Zeroes are the x-intercepts of a function. Unlike the domain, you will not always have zeroes in a function. For instance, quadratic functions that are translated vertically upward lose their zeroes if they open upward, and vice versa for downward translations. For sine and cosine functions, vertical translations greater than the radius of their respective circles lose their zeroes (e.g, greater than 2 or less than -2 for a circle with radius 2). To calculate this, set y = 0 and solve for your x-values.

End behavior describes the y-values of polynomials as x approaches -infinity and as x approaches infinity. This applies when your domain is all real numbers. For polynomials with even degrees, y will approach infinity for both cases. For odd degree polynomials, y approaches -infinity as x approaches -infinity and infinity as x approaches infinity. Your symmetry (if it exists) is super helpful here.

It does not make sense to apply end behavior to trigonometric functions since the values of f(x) "oscillate" between arbitrary values r and -r and since the periodicity (repetitions) of the functions leaves no endpoint.

Quadratic functions: You are given either a form ax^2+bx+c or a(x-h)^2+k. The "other component" here is a vertex, since the range of quadratics have either a minimum or maximum depending on whether a is positive or negative (respectively).
The vertex is the "turning point" of the quadratic, which is either -b/(2a) or (h,k).

Polynomials: You have a form similar to a0+a1x+a2x^2+...+anx^n, where each a is a coefficient and a0 is a constant. If a0 is not 0, you cannot have an odd function but might still have an even function. To find the zeroes and possible even symmetry, you either factor your polynomial, use the quadratic formula (if applicable), or use the rational root theorem, which states that dividing your polynomial by another polynomial (x-h) will result in h being a zero if the remainder of the quotient is 0. If you have only pairs of zeroes (such as 7 and -7) with the same "other component" multiplicity (repeated roots) then your function is even.

Trigonometric functions: your forms may look like asin/cos/tan+k. For sine and cosine functions, the range is bounded between (k-a) and (k+a), but the range for tangent functions is all real numbers. The "other component" here is periodicity (see end behavior). Periodicity describes when each value of f(x) repeats. For instance, if b = 1/2 and you have a standard sine function, you get sin(2x). The 1/2 means that it takes 1/2 the time for each cycle of the sine function to repeat. For b = 1, your standard cycle is every multiple (2pi) of x. Thus for the example every multiple pi of x creates a new cycle. Tangent functions also have asymptotes whenever f(x) = tan(pi/2). So for tan(4x) < periodicity of 1/4> your asymptotes occur at every multiple (pi/8) of x. Thus your asymptotes occur at every multiple of 1/(2b).

Hope this helps!